# How do I find objects of a certain type in a Class in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

I am going to assume that I have to use `System.Reflection`. However when I want to build a list of `typeA` that have been defined before, how would I build that list?

```
public TypeA foo;
System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes?
```

I'm not really sure how to better phrase the question. I'm just looking to build a list of all the `TypeA` occurrences in my class.

Comment: Do you want to enumerate the properties of your class, and filter those that are of type TypeA ?

Comment: Gerardo, yes that is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: So this is what I'm looking for? typeof(Foo).GetProperties();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above comments it seems like you already know what you want to do. But heres a quick example

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var properties = typeof(MyObject).GetProperties();
        var stringsInMyObject = properties.Where(x=> x.GetMethod.ReturnType == typeof(string));
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public string SomeString2 { get; set; }
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    public int SomeInt2 { get; set; }
}
```